# x32 executables in fasm

Tags: linux-x32-abi, fasm

> "format ELF executable 3" makes an x86 executable
>   "format ELF64 executable 3" makes an x64 executable

But how can I make an [x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) (x64 with 32-bit pointers) executable?

p.s. What does "3" mean after "executable" in these lines?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there:
https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=195644

p.s. In can be made by **fasmg**:

```
ELF.Settings.Class = ELFCLASS32 
ELF.Settings.Machine = EM_X86_64 
ELF.Settings.ABI = ELFOSABI_LINUX 
include 'format/elfexe.inc' 
include 'x64.inc' 
use64
```